# Spring Boot Flyway applying database migration to wrong database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, flyway

I am attempting to configure Spring Boot and Flyway to apply separate migrations to two different datasources using Spring Boot 2.2.6 and Flyway 5.2.3.

The primary datasource:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.gobsmack.*.repository.primary"},
                       entityManagerFactoryRef = "primaryEntityManagerFactory",
                       transactionManagerRef = "primaryTransactionManager"
)
public class PrimaryDatasourceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.primary-datasource")
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "primaryEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean primaryEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder.dataSource(primaryDataSource())
                .packages("com.gobsmack.*.model")
                .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager primaryTransactionManager(
            final @Qualifier("primaryEntityManagerFactory") LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean primaryEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(primaryEntityManagerFactory.getObject());
    }
}
```

The second datasource:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.gobsmack.*.repository.secondary"},
                       entityManagerFactoryRef = "secondaryEntityManagerFactory",
                       transactionManagerRef = "secondaryTransactionManager"
)
public class SecondaryDatasourceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.secondary-datasource")
    public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "secondaryEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean secondaryEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder.dataSource(secondaryDataSource())
                .packages("com.gobsmack.*.model")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager secondaryTransactionManager(
            final @NonNull @Qualifier("secondaryEntityManagerFactory") LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean secondaryEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(secondaryEntityManagerFactory.getObject());
    }
}
```

The datasource connection properties:

```
spring:
  primary-datasource:
    jdbc-url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/primary?useSSL=false&primary
    password: password
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    username: username
  secondary-datasource:
    jdbc-url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/secondary?useSSL=false&secondary
    password: password
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    username: username
```

The Flyway migration:

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class FlywayConfiguration {

    public static final String DB_MIGRATION_BASE = "db/migration/";

    private DataSource primaryDataSource;
    private DataSource secondaryDataSource;

    @Value("${spring.primary-datasource.jdbc-url:localhost}")
    private String primaryDatasourceUrl;

    @Value("${spring.secondary-datasource.jdbc-url:localhost}")
    private String secondaryDatasourceUrl;

    @Autowired
    public FlywayConfiguration(@Qualifier("primaryDataSource") DataSource primaryDataSource,
                               @Qualifier("secondaryDataSource") DataSource secondaryDataSource) {
        this.primaryDataSource = primaryDataSource;
        this.secondaryDataSource = secondaryDataSource;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void migrate() {
        log.info("Preparing Flyway migration for database with url: " + primaryDatasourceUrl);
        migrateDatabase(primaryDataSource, "primary");

        log.info("Preparing Flyway migration for database with url: " + secondaryDatasourceUrl);
        migrateDatabase(secondaryDataSource, "secondary");
    }

    /**
     * Migrate specific database.
     * @param datasource The datasource.
     * @param directories The directories containing the migration scripts.
     */
    private void migrateDatabase(@NonNull DataSource datasource, @NonNull String... directories) {
        for (val directory : directories) {
            log.info("Migration scripts source: " + directory);
            new Flyway(Flyway.configure()
                             .dataSource(datasource)
                             .locations(DB_MIGRATION_BASE + directory))
                             .migrate();
        }
    }
}
```

The directory structure:

[image]

Migration script `V1.0.0_1__secondary__init.sql` is correctly only applied to the `secondary` database.

The issue is that the scripts inside both `db/migration/primary` and `db/migration/secondary` are being applied to the `primary` database, when only the scripts in the primary directory should be being applied.

How do I configure Flyway to only apply the migration scripts in the directory  `db/migration/primary` to the `primary` database?

Answer (score 0):

I had to disable the automatic running of Flyway that was looking up scripts to apply to the `@Primary` annotated database. It was finding all migration scripts in subdirectories of `db/migration`.

So in the `application.yml` configuration file I had to add:

```
spring:
  flyway:
    enabled: false
```